# How to get first span element of a div and change class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a span

```
<div id="div1">
    <span class="">hello</span>
</div>
```

When i click on div i want to change the class of only first span element of the div

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
    // ... check if first span element inside the div .. if there and change the class..    
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('#div1').click(function() {    
   $('span:first', this).prop('class', 'newClassName');
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

http://jsfiddle.net/BUBb9/1/

Answer (score 8):

use

```
 $("div span:first-child")
```

as follow:

```
$('#div1').click(function() {    
   $('span:first', this).prop('class', 'ClassName');
})
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
    var v = $(this).find('span').text();
});
```

Like this you can get the value of span.

You can also use .html() instead of .text() method.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple answers valid. My approach:

```
$('#div1').click(function() {    
     $(this).find('span').first().attr('class','newClassName');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div1').click(function() {    
   $('#div1 span:first').attr('class', 'newClassName');
});
```

Comment: This will set the class on another `span`, in case you have another span somewhere else before (outside the div as well).

Comment: try this one $('#div1').click(function() {    
   $('#div1 span:first').attr('class', 'newClassName');
});